# How to add/install the graphicx package to LaTeX?

Tags: graphics, packages, installing

This is likely a naive and simple question, so apologies for that. I'm trying to incorporate figures in TeXworks. I understand I need to use the `graphicx` package. What I can't figure out is whether I need to install something before I put the `\usepackage{graphicx}` into the preamble.
If so, I have downloaded the `.ins`-file from CTAN and it's in the folder with all the other `.tex` docs, but not sure how to "activate" it from there.

Thank you

Comment: the package is usually included in the basic installation of either MiKTeX or TeX Live distributions. it would help, if you could provide a.) information about your technical layout and b.) a minimal working example of what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Welcome! You shouldn't need to install anything.

Comment: Look first for `graphicx.sty` in your installation. It should already be there.

Comment: graphicx is part of the required core of the latex distribution, if you have latex without graphicx (which seems unlikely) then report that as an error to whoever distributed the latex that you are using.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others, `graphicx` should be installed already, and you don't need to do anything more than `\usepackage{graphicx}` into your preamble. It is highly unlikely in my opinion that you have a TeX-installation which doesn't include this package.

To install/update packages in the future, you can have a look at this post: [How do I update my TeX distribution?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-do-i-update-my-tex-distribution)

Here is a quick test-example which uses `graphicx`

#### Output

[image]

#### Code

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[hbt]
\centering
  \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-a}
  \caption{An example image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```